# Magento 2: How to put default value in yes/no field of admin UI component form

Tags: magento2

I have a UI component **Form** checkbox. I want it to default to **yes** rather than no.

This is my Field

```
<field name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox-toggle-notice</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">template</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Please confirm you wish to proceed ?</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <field name="status" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
            <dataScope>status</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create default a configuration for your admin items in

```
app/code/VendorName/MyModule/etc/config.xml

<default>
<section>
   <group>
       <field>{value}</field>
   </group>
</section>
</default>
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
       <default>
           <section_id>
               <group_id>
                   <my_boolean_option>1</my_boolean_option>
               </group_id>
           </section_id>
       </default>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
    <field name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Please confirm you wish to proceed ?</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="boolean" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```